# Decomposition of tensor product of two representations of $so(10,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

There exist two 16-dimensional irreducible non-isomorphic representations of $so(10,\mathbb{C})$. Consider the tensor products of each of them with the standard (10-dimensional) representation.

**What is the decomposition of these two tensor products into irreducible components (number of components, multiplicities, dimensions)?**

Comment: This question is not at a suitable level for MO.

Comment: You should be able to answer questions like these with the web interface of LiE, which does not require downloading the software. That is how I would do it. You need to learn how LiE organizes its notation for reps, but it is not so difficult. http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html

Comment: @BenMcKay Agreed. The web interface for LiE hasn't been working for me for several months now. Is that just me or is it completely down?

Comment: @Callum: thanks for pointing that out; I should have tried LiE once more before recommending it. Apparently the web interface is not working. Sorry.